# Importing and using groovy code in GSP

Tags: grails, groovy, import, gsp

I am trying to use a groovy function inside a GSP.  Please help as I am about to tare my hair out here.

At the top of my GSP i have `<%@ page import = company.ConstantsFile %>`

Inside my GSP I have

```
<p>
I have been in the heating and cooling business for <%(ConstantsFile.daysBetween())%>
</p>
```

and my ConstantsFile.groovy

```
package company

import static java.util.Calendar.*

class ConstantsFile {

    def daysBetween() {
        def startDate = Calendar.instance
        def m = [:]
        m[YEAR] = 2004
        m[MONTH] = "JUNE"
        m[DATE] = 26
        startDate.set(m)
        def today = Calendar.instance

        render today - startDate
    }
}
```

I have also tried changing renter to puts, system.out, etc but that isn't my main problem.

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI
/company/
Class
java.lang.NullPointerException
Message
Cannot invoke method daysBetween() on null object
```

So I try

```
<p>
    I have been in the heating and cooling business for <%(new ConstantsFile.daysBetween())%>
    </p>
```

but then i get

```
Class: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException

unable to resolve class ConstantsFile.daysBetween @ line 37, column 1. (new ConstantsFile.daysBetween()) ^ 1 error
```

Please someone help me or point me to a website that shows what to do.. I have tried googling and everything talks about a g:select or some other kind of tag... I just want to output the result of the function like I used to in the JSPs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, your GSP's import should be:

```
<%@ page import="company.ConstantsFile" %>
```

Second, your daysBetween should be static (it makes more sense) and you don't render from anything but a controller:

```
class ConstantsFile {

    static daysBetween() {
        def startDate = Calendar.instance
        def m = [:]
        m[YEAR] = 2004
        m[MONTH] = "JUNE"
        m[DATE] = 26
        startDate.set(m)
        def today = Calendar.instance

        return today - startDate
    }
}
```

Third, access it in the following way:

```
<p>I have been in the heating and cooling business for ${ConstantsFile.daysBetween}</p>
```

And lastly, you should use a taglib for this.  I'm editing my post now to add an example

```
class MyTagLib {

  static namespace = "my"

  def daysBetween = { attr ->
     out << ConstantsFile.daysBetween()
  }
}
```

Then use in your GSP

```
<p>I have been in the heating and cooling business for <my:daysBetween /></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried the first way you suggested to me and I get the following error:
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI
/company/
Class
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message
No signature of method: static company.ConstantsFile.daysBetween() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: daysBetween()

Comment: OK. i am so sorry to do this, but It was the Calendar instance and math I was trying to do on it.  +1 and accept for helpin me out