# What is the correct way to import a Class in a GSP?

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I've seen imports of type `<%@ page import=...` but `<%!import com....` also works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#pageDirectives) shows the first form:

```
<%@ page import="java.awt.*" %>
```

However, as stated there and in [other questions on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14698535/6509) you should probably be using a taglib for this

Comment: @BurtBeckwith What is the advantage of using TagLibs over writing code on the view?

Comment: That's way too big a question to answer in the comments

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the class without specifying:

```
   <%@ page import="java.awt.*" %>.
```

e.g,

```
  <g:each in=${com.test.User.list()} var="test">
  </g:each>
```